Making Excel Worksheet Copy with ExcelJS
What I'm trying to do is create a functionality in my LWC component that allows the user to download an exact copy of an XLSX doc from a template.
I have successfully loaded ExcelJS into my component. However, I'm not sure how to go about the rest. Should I:

Save the XLSX template to Salesforce Files, and somehow retrieve it and use ExcelJS to make a copy of it?

Save the XLSX template as a Static Resource and then retrieve it using ExcelJS to make a copy?


My main concern is being able to download the XLSX template with all its formatting, including colored cells, merged cells, etc. I've lightly tried both without success but I'm not really finding resources out there on how to actually go about this successfully. Here's my very limited code so far, in case it helps:
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import exceljs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JsExcelLib';
import jsziplib from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JsZipLib';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TestExcelDownload extends LightningElement {

    isExcelJSLoaded = false;
    isJSZipLoaded = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        var regeneratorRuntime = undefined;
        window.regeneratorRuntime = regeneratorRuntime;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, exceljs),
            loadScript(this, jsziplib)
        ]).then(() => {
            this.isExcelJSLoaded = true;
            this.isJSZipLoaded = true;
            console.log('ExcelJS and JSZip loaded successfully');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading ExcelJS or JSZip:', error);
        });
    }

    handleDownload() {
        console.log('handleDownload clicked')
    }

}


You'll have an easier time if you use a doc gen tool like Conga / Apsona to merge data into an XLSX template, or use a tool like XL Connector to pull data directly into an XLSX.
